# How to retrieve the Query string value from web word instance

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I'm creating a web add-in for Word targeting Word Online. When a document is opened using Word Online, the URL will contain a file name. I am trying to retrieve that file name.

To retrieve this URL I tried using `window.location` href, but it is fetching my hosted addin web application URL. Is it possible to get the Word Online URL?

Sample Code :

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.search;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What you should use instead?

You should use Office.js API that's defined here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document

`Office.context.document.url` this should return you something that you can use.

#### Why didn't your solution work?

Unfortunately this is not possible the way you're trying to implement it due to security requirements around iFrames. Word Online is using an iFrame to host your add-in and accessing the parent window from an iFrame is generally very restricted unless you're specifically allowed.

You can however get the base host url of the parent window by looking into the `referrer` header, but that's pretty much it. I understand that this is not sufficient for you, which is why I'm recommending to use the Word API.

You can see a bit more documentation below about iFrames:

- iFrame spec documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html
- On getting the url that's loading the frame (the parent URL): https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2013/04/16/getting-the-url-of-an-iframes-parent/
- Some more information on how to communicate between parent and the iFrame using `postMessage` API if you were whitelisted (which you aren't): https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/cross-domain-iframe-parent-communication-403912fff692

Comment: as suggested i used Office.context.document.url but with this i am getting the absolute path of the document (Sample :https://mydomain.xyz/personal/personal_com/Documents/AddinTest.docx ) and not the actual online word url

Comment: yeah - but it looks like you have the file name in that one right?

Comment: I am using Office.context.document.url to fetch the url of the online word i.e https://mydomain.xyz/:w:/r/personal/personal_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B6FEF6215-DD54-4BFF-B12C-2D762C0932AC%7D&file=AddinTest.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true but the output is https://mydomain.xyz/personal/personal_com/Documents/AddinTest.docx . my requirement is to read the full url and associated querystring

Comment: Unless that meta-information that you're looking for is present in the `Office.context.document` I don't think you can get it. I've already explained the limitation that you're hitting, you can't read iFrame's parent information. You said you were trying to get the filename which is in this api. You just need to read the last bit of it. If you're looking to get the query string for something other than the filename, I don't think it will be possible.

Comment: Yes. really appreciate your help to find the filename. My actual problem statement is passing some information from my source application to AddIn. This could be something more than filename. My idea was to pass the extra parameters through custom query string, read it using addin api and then load parameter specific data. If you say querystring couldn't be read using this method then could you please suggest any other way I can pass parameter from my source application to word addin?